# Will parents full of Dhamma attract good minds for their babies?

Tags: rebirth

Is it more likely that a mind with more positive Kamma and closer to the Dhamma will reborn as a son of a couple that follows the Dhmma? Is there like an attraction due to the Dhamma?

There is a story that Buddha once told a couple that if they have the same religion, similar dana and sila they may meet again in the next life.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Suminda said. What usually happens is, whatever is a *hidden* trait in parents, it attracts a child mind with the same trait manifested *explicitly*. This works both ways, good and bad. If parents quietly despise imperfect people, they will attract the child mind that *openly* hates the whole world and may eventually develop a drug addiction or something. The same way, parents with few attachments will attract a child mind that may be *too* unfettered, perhaps to the point of having issues in school etc. So it's not as much bad => bad and good => good, as it is inner => outer and subtle => explicit.

Answer (score 0):

In Buddhism there is no definiteness in Karma. Since there is not definiteness we can just say there is a higher probability this might happen.